# CheckSum error, cannot boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, acer-aspire, checksum

I was watching a video on my Acer Aspire laptop when I accidentally hit it on the left side of screen with my leg, the hit was very minor. But just after the hit the video stuck and started giving a weird sound. I held the power button and switched off the laptop. When I tried to power it on again it would only give a black screen, not even the Acer logo appears. After repeated power on and off it shows the logo sometimes and gets stuck on that logo screen, while sometimes it does not show anything. Once it showed the Checksum error screen whose image you can see here:

[image]

Comment: You have damaged your hard disk. Follow the instructions in the screen shot and perform a recovery.

Comment: How can a hit to the screen can cause that problem and I am not able to go to that screen again , the screen either freezes at acer logo screen or does not show anything

Comment: It's a laptop. Hitting the screen shakes the whole laptop. If your disk was writing at the time of the impact it can be damaged.